# category_count gives wrong number of posts in category

Tags: categories

I have a bilangual page where posts are sorted by categories and subcategories. When i check hoew many posts are actually displayed on a category page I get 312 in both languages. When I check the admin table for that same category it shows 291 posts for one language and 301 posts for the other language. Also when I count the posts with php in the template archive.php as shown below I get 291 / 301 instead of 312 posts.

```
$current_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

$category = get_category($current_cat_id);

$count = $category->category_count;
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions / pointers appreciated.

UPDATE: On this page http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/09/21/get_category_count/index.html I found a function titled "get_category_count" and after placing it in functions.php and calling it with the category slug it first seemed to give the correct results. But the results actually still differ from what i see in the admin columns when filtering for the same category.

```
function wt_get_category_count($input = '') {
    global $wpdb;
    if($input == '')
    {
        $category = get_the_category();
        return $category[0]->category_count;
    }
    elseif(is_numeric($input))
    {
        $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id=$input";
        return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
    }
    else
    {
        $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->terms.slug='$input'";
    return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
    }
}
```

What am i kissing? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your issue is cached values at all, but `get_category()` does cache results, so it's a possibility.

Here are some other options:

```
$current_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

$category = get_category($current_cat_id);

// One possibility:
$count_a = get_category_count( $category->slug );

// OR... another possibility:
$count_b = wp_count_terms( $category->slug );
```

Comment: a) Thank you for your suggestions! However,  wp_count_terms gives a result that is totally off since it "Counts how many terms are in taxonomy." (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_terms/) whereas I am looking for the number of posts in a given category.

Comment: b) To my knowledge the function get_category_count is not a built in function, but it lead my in the right direction: On this page http://www.web-templates.nu/2008/09/21/get_category_count/index.html I found a function titled "get_category_count" and after placing it in functions.php it seems to give the correct results. So thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!